# CSV Import: How can I import related products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, import, csv, related-products

How can I import related products via csv in Magento 2?

In my csv file I have a row with attribute **related_skus** with example data "11-111,22-222" for a product. But in admin *Products->Catalog* in this imported product the sidebar tab *Related Products* show **no** products although those products with skus exist in catalog.

Where can be the mistake?

Comment: Magento showed any errors? What's is your Import Behavior: Add/Update, Replace or Delete?

Comment: No errors, import was successfully completed. Import Behavior was "Add/Update".

Comment: You try to re-index your database?

Comment: Yes, I used the command **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** and flushed the cache. I used pipe "|" as _Multiple value separator_ and the example data was "11-111|22-222". Perhaps Magento doesn't support another multiple value separator for **related_skus** attribute?

Comment: Have you been achieve to import your products now ?

Comment: I have posted our working solution for this problem

Answer (score 7):

We've experienced the same issue, it seems import module has some kind of bug with related products

We've solved it by writing a new console command which expects a 2 columns (parent sku & children skus) **related.csv** file in **var** folder, with comma as csv separator, and pipe as children_skus separator

This are the files, if you want to try. You'd replace **Sinapsis** with your desired vendor name, and **Sync** with your desired module name

After installing the module, run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` & you'll see the new command if you check `bin/magento list`, which could be executed by running `bin/magento sync:related`

**update**

Since 2.2.* version, there are 2 changes required: an extra line before saving `$product`, to prevent issue reported here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10687

```
$product->unsetData('media_gallery');
```

And changing **admin** to **adminhtml** in

```
$this->_appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
```

I think first change is innocuous for older versions, not the same for the second. So I have added only the first in below code

**app / code / Sinapsis / Sync / etc / di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sync_related" xsi:type="object">Sinapsis\Sync\Console\Command\RelatedCommand</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**app / code / Sinapsis / Sync / etc / module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="module.xsd">
<module name="Sinapsis_Sync" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```

**app / code / Sinapsis / Sync / registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sinapsis_Sync',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app / code / Sinapsis / Sync / Console / Command / RelatedCommand.php**

```
<?php
namespace Sinapsis\Sync\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class RelatedCommand extends Command
{
    const CSV_SEPARATOR = ',';
    const CHILDREN_SEPARATOR = '|';

    protected $_appState;
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_directorylist;

    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $_directorylist,
        AppState $appState,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_appState = $appState;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_directorylist = $_directorylist;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('sync:related')
            ->setDescription('Synchronize catalog related products');
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('<info>Starting process...<info>');
        $output->writeln('');

        $this->_appState->setAreaCode('admin');
        $productRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
        $output->writeln('<info>Loading csv content...<info>');
        $output->writeln('');

        $filePath = $this->_directorylist->getPath('var') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'related.csv';
        //@todo control Exception if file does not exist
        $parseData = array();
        if (($handle = fopen($filePath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, self::CSV_SEPARATOR)) !== FALSE) {
                $parseData[] = $data;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            $output->writeln('<info>Could not read .csv file<info>');
            return;
        }
        $headers = array_shift($parseData); // remove headers

        foreach ($parseData as $row){

            $skuParent = trim($row[0]);
            $skuChildren = trim($row[1]);
            $output->writeln('<info>Loading parent product ' . $skuParent . ' ... <info>');

            try {
                $product = $productRepository->get($skuParent);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
                $output->writeln('<info>Could not load!<info>');
                continue;
            }

            $links = $product->getProductLinks();
            $children = explode(self::CHILDREN_SEPARATOR, $skuChildren);

            $i = 1;
            foreach ($children as $skuChild){

                $output->writeln('<info>Loading related product ' . $skuChild . ' ... <info>');

                try {
                    $child = $productRepository->get($skuChild);
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
                    $output->writeln('<info>Could not load!<info>');
                    continue;
                }

                $productLink = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface')
                    ->setSku($skuParent)
                    ->setLinkedProductSku($skuChild)
                    ->setPosition($i)
                    ->setLinkType('related');
                $links[] = $productLink;
                $i++;
            }

            $product->setProductLinks($links);
            $product->unsetData('media_gallery');
            $productRepository->save($product);
            $output->writeln('<info>Relations saved for ' . $skuParent . '<info>');

        }
        $output->writeln('');
        $output->writeln('<info>Done<info>');
    }
}
```

Comment: is this code will work while creating new products but as far as i checked your code here you are adding related products to the existing parent sku.

Comment: If you have any idea while creating parent sku only can we add some related/upsell/crossel skus to that product. Please suggest me thanks in Advance.

Comment: This code worked for me thanks @Raul Sanchez